# Kapt and Ksp not working Android studio, and ' ' not working in Gradle need to put " "

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I am new to app development.
First I figured out that I need to work with Gradle in "" not in '' like in most
videos //and places I visited and not sure why.
I tried to make kapt or ksp work but couldn't find a way to do it.

**Ksp**
Tried like in android site https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

**app Gradle**

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    } 
} 

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Line `ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0")`

error `Unresolved reference: ksp (ksp highlaited in red)`

**project Gradle**

```
 plugins {
     id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
     id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
 }
```

**Error**

Exception is:

```
 org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.devtools.ksp']   
 Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
 - Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

**Kapt**

```
android 
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' 
// (shows error: Expecting an element)

//  kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
// Kept highlated in red
```

**app Gradle**

```
plugins  
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' 

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2")
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
    ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle in plugin version 4.0 added support for Kotlin to replace Groovy - https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl

With quotes, you are reffering to:

**Double quotes for strings:** While Groovy allows strings to be defined using single quotes, Kotlin requires double quotes.

The simillar applies for Kapt to KSP: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

---

EDIT:

As for ksp/kapt, I am not so sure, but in my working project (library but it should be the same):

**Top level build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.22' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.7.22-1.0.8' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.3' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

**Module specific build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
}

android {
    ...  
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    ...

    // Moshi support
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0'
    ksp 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0'
    // Moshi end

}
```

Comment: Didn't get what I have to do to make kapt or ksp work.

Comment: Edited the answer with example of my project with `ksp`. Hope it helps.